# Problem using numpy to obtain the complex conjugate of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, complex-numbers

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[2, 2-9j, -5j], [4-1j, 0, 9+6j], [4j, 6+7j, 6]])
print(A)
print(A.getH())
```

It doesn't work. I have checked different webs and followed [this webpage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-numpy-matrix-geth/) (geeksforgeeks), and [this other](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.H.html)(official numpy documentation) but I still get an error and I don't know where. Can someone please help me?

The error is `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getH'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, a numpy array doesn't have a method `getH`. Your [second link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.H.html) actually is the official documentation, and it shows that the method is **not** called `getH`. Read the documentation closely!

Comment: You are right, I have changed the code to `A_332=np.matrix([[3, 2-1j, -5j], [2+1j, 0, 9-5j], [5j, 9+5j, 6]])` and now works

Comment: `numpy.matrix` instances do actually have a [`getH` method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getH.html#numpy.matrix.getH). It's `numpy.ndarray` that doesn't have that method.

Comment: Note that both the geeksforgeeks link and the NumPy documentation link in the question go to pages about `numpy.matrix`. If the questioner had tried the `H` property they found in the official documentation, it still wouldn't have worked, because they were looking at documentation for `numpy.matrix`, which is the wrong class.

Comment: `.H` is the `property` version of the `.getH` method.  The `.H` docs page does use `getH` in its example.  By the docs and source code the equivalent would be `np.cong(A.T)`.  (Where `T` is the property version of `transpose`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `numpy.conj()` function.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[2, 2-9j, -5j], [4-1j, 0, 9+6j], [4j, 6+7j, 6]])
print(A)
print(A.conj())
```

Output

```
[[ 2.+0.j  2.-9.j -0.-5.j]
 [ 4.-1.j  0.+0.j  9.+6.j]
 [ 0.+4.j  6.+7.j  6.+0.j]]
[[ 2.-0.j  2.+9.j -0.+5.j]
 [ 4.+1.j  0.-0.j  9.-6.j]
 [ 0.-4.j  6.-7.j  6.-0.j]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at pages about the `numpy.matrix` class, but the `numpy.array` function creates instances of `numpy.ndarray`, not `numpy.matrix`.

You could use `numpy.matrix`, but that's a bad idea. `numpy.matrix` has a lot of weird compatibility problems, and its use is discouraged in new code. Instead, use [`numpy.conj`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.conj.html):

```
print(numpy.conj(A))
```